# How to get total number of variables in an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Google wasn't my friend on this one... maybe I wasn't searching for the right terms.

I have a javascript array `randomTagLine[0]`, `randomTagLine[1]`, etc. How do I get the total number of variables in the array? For instance, I can physically see there are 23, but I need to pull that out via JS code...

Thanks in advance..

**EDIT**

Example of code:

```
var randomTagline = new Array();
randomTagline[0] = "TEXT0";
randomTagline[1] = "TEXT1";
randomTagline[2] = "TEXT2";
//...
randomTagline[23] = "TEXT23";
var randomTaglineLength = randomTagLine.length;

var randomTaglineNum = randomXToY(0,randomTaglineLength,0);

alert(randomTaglineNum + " " + randomTaglineLength);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's :

```
 var length = randomTagLine.length;
```

Comment: I'm getting a `randomTagLine is not defined` on that, even though it's defined earlier as `var randomTagline = new Array();` any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a little more code ? Like for example, where are you defining the array, filling it, and testing the length ?

Comment: Found it... it was an "L" instead of a "l"... Thanks for your help!

Comment: You got it like 2 seconds before me :p